# Huge difference in MySQL query executiontime, same query, same result set size

Tags: mysql

we are currently having some strange behavior regarding the executiontime of two of our queries. But as an example I'll describe one of those.

The query itself is not that complex. It collects a small dataset based on two parameters. Normally this query has an execution time in the range of 0.01 - 0.04 seconds. Unless a specific set of parameters is given, then the execution time drastically increases to 70 to 80 seconds.

This is reproduceable every single time. This specific query runs thousands of times a day with hundreds of different parameter pairs with no problem at all. But if these specific values are given, it will take an immense time to finish. We have reproduced this manually many times, always with the same result. We know that it is not caused by server load, that was one of the first things we checked and there is the same execution time even if the server load very low.

So what we can rule out as a reason by now is, server load and result set size.
Additionally, other parameters are giving the exact same result set with no increased execution time, so not only the resultset size is not an issue, also the actual data in the result does not seem to have any impact.

If it helps, the query itself looks like this:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT( m.column1 SEPARATOR '^') as export from TABLE1 b 
join TABLE2 m on b.column2 = m.column3
join TABLE3 t on b.column4 = t.column5 
where t.column6 = parameter1 and t.column7 = parameter2;
```

This query has been used for years now and never caused that kind of problem. Any help on this issue would be greatly appreciated.

**Update in regard to Akinas comment:**

We have run analyze and optimize on every table involved, which sadly did not change the behavior.

Running the problematic query on a copy of the database on the same server does not show the long execution time.

Running an explain and comparing the plans showed, that there are differences between the normal and the problematic one.
However, on the test database the execution plan of the problematic query is not different from the execution plan on the original DB, but still the execution time differs wildly.

Problematic:

```
| id | select_type | table  | type   | key     | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | m      | index  | key_b   | 18      | NULL           | 75   | Using index | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | b      | ref    | PRIMARY | 4       | db.table.index | 311  | Using index | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | t      | eq_ref | PRIMARY | 8       | db.table.index | 1    | Using where |
```

normal:

```
| id | select_type | table | type   | key     | key_len | ref            | rows | Extra | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | t     | ref    | fk_1    | 4       | const          | 4931 | Using where | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | b     | ref    | fk_2    | 8       | db.table.index | 2    | Using index | 
| 1  | SIMPLE      | m     | eq_ref | PRIMARY | 4       | db.table.index | 1    | NULL |
```

Comment: Firstly check execution plans - when regular and when problematic parameter values are provided. Does they differ? Then check does the problem remains on the tables copies restored on test server - maybe some service procedures needed over your tables (analyze, optimise)?

Comment: @Akina Thank you, I have updated the question following your suggestions

Comment: Reorder FROM clause according to "normal" plan and add STRAIGHT_JOIN.

Comment: @Akina Thank you, adding one STRAIGHT_JOIN fixed the issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just to mark this as answered

Akinas comment suggesting to add a STRAIGHT_JOIN fixed the problem completely.

The actual change looks like that:

```
select GROUP_CONCAT( m.column1 SEPARATOR '^') as export from TABLE1 b 
STRAIGHT_JOIN TABLE2 m on b.column2 = m.column3
join TABLE3 t on b.column4 = t.column5 
where t.column6 = parameter1 and t.column7 = parameter2;
```

This reduced the execution time of the query with the problematic parameters to a normal level. Thank you very much.